# Grenzfälle Dativ/Akkusativ

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Mir fallen immer wieder Beispiele ein, bei denen ich grammatikalisch den Dativ verwenden würde, aber rein vom Sprachegefühl her eindeutig der Akkusativ richtig klingt.

Bspw.
*Verbrennungen behandelt man heute mit lauwarmem Wasser*

Ich kann fragen mit *wem* ich Verbrennungen behandeln würde und *dir* einsetzen.
*Wen* Und *dich* sind beide grammatikalisch falsch.

Phonetisch würde ich aber ohne nachzudenken "*lauwarmen Wasser*" sagen.

Was ist richtig und wieso?
Hat das einen bestimmten Namen?

Comment: Aus welcher Region stammst du? Für mich (Norddeutschland) klingt der Akkusativ sehr falsch an der Stelle.

Comment: @infinitezero Südösterreich

Answer (score 11):

Mein Verdacht ist, dass es gar möglicherweise gar nicht um Dativ oder Akkusativ geht, sondern um starke oder schwache Flexion.

Die Präposition *mit* verlangt ausnahmslos den Dativ. Insofern kommt hier der Akkusativ auf keinen Fall in Betracht.

Allerdings sind Varianten des Beispielsatzes möglich, in denen sehr wohl *lauwarmen Wasser* korrekt ist, nämlich wenn ein Artikel oder ein Artikelwort vorhanden ist:

> Verbrennungen behandelt man heute mit *dem lauwarmen* Wasser.

(Dass der Artikel hier logisch keinen Sinn macht, blende ich mal aus)

Es kann sein, dass in manchen Regionen die Bedingung des Vorhandenseins eines Artikelworts für die Verwendung der schwachen Flexion als nicht so zwingend empfunden wird. (Dialekteinfluss?)

Eine andere Möglichkeit ist, dass in lokalen Dialekten der Endlaut entfällt (ich kenne das aus den mir bekannten südhessischen Dialekten), wodurch der Unterschied zwischen -en und -em verwischt wird (warmen/warmem → warme). Wenn dann ins Standarddeutsche 'übersetzt' wird, wird u.U. automatisch ein -n ergänzt, auch wo ein -m richtig wäre.

Im Standarddeutschen und auch nach meinem Sprachgefühl muss es allerdings ohne Artikel zwingend *mit lauwarmem Wasser* lauten. *Mit lauwarmen Wasser* ist für mich schlicht falsch.

Comment: Darf ich fragen, aus welcher Region du stammst? Im Österreichischen passiert es wirklich öfters, dass der Endlaut verschwindet, allerdings ist der pfälzische Dialekt, mit dem ich vertraut bin für mich trotzdem sehr merkwürdig. Wir kürzen eher "ich" nach "i" und manchmal sind die Kürzungen und Laute sehr kontextuell (bspw können "owi" und "owe" was Anderes bedeuten, aber nicht in allen Dialekten). Für mich persönlich klingt der Dativ an Adjektiven gesprochen etwas merkwürdig.

Comment: @Qohelet Aus Südhessen, die dortigen Dialekte gehören wie das Pfälzische zum Rheinfränkischen. Diese Dialekte haben die 2. Lautverschiebung nur teilweise mitgemacht, weswegen es z.B. *Appel* statt *Apfel* heißt.

Comment: Guter Gedanke. Die Dativ-Endung eines Adjektivs auf -m stößt dem faulen oder ungenauen (also Alltags- ;-) ) Sprecher tatsächlich etwas auf, und es gibt ja eine Tendenz, bei einer Aneinanderreihung von Attributen nur das erste stark zu beugen: "Mit lautem, nicht enden wollenden Beifall" klingt nicht einmal richtig falsch. Vielleicht erleben wir hier den Anfang vom Ende der starken Beugung? Ist ja auch eine grammatische Extra-Locke (die immer wieder neu gelernt werden muss), dass die Beugung vom Vorhandensein eines Artikels abhängt.

Answer (score 7):

Richtig ist auf jeden Fall nur *mit lauwarmem Wasser*. Aber das Problem -m/-n kann ich als Wiener gut nachvollziehen. Ich vermute auch, dass es eher mit starker/schwacher Flexion zusammenhängt, die in österreichischen Dialekten oft verschwimmt. Aus meinem Bauchgefühl heraus würde mir die starke Flexion in diesem Satzbeispiel auf Wienerisch z.B. sehr seltsam vorkommen (*mit lauwoarmem Wossa*), natürlicher wäre es mit dem unbestimmten Artikel (*mit an lauwoarmen Wossa*, wo *-n* richtig ist), auch wenn das grammatikalisch zwar richtig ist, aber ein unbestimmter Artikel vor unzählbaren Nomen wie *Wasser*, *Milch* standardsprachlich ein ziemlicher Schwachsinn ist.

Comment: *Mit an lauwoarmen Wossa* = *Mit einem lauwarmen Wasser* ist sogar korrekt, wegen des unbestimmten Artikels.

Comment: Allerdings haben wir dann bei *an* = *einem* wieder den Wechsel von -n nach -m.

Comment: @Rha nicht im Dialekt. Da sagt man "mit a*n*" wasauchimmer

Comment: Für mich ergibt diese Antwort durchaus Sinn. Mir ist schon öfters aufgefallen, dass im Dialekt die Fälle generell in Richtung Akkusativ gehen. Teilweise wird sogar der Genitiv mit dem Akkusativ substituiert. In diesem Fall würde kein Artikel dazu passen, da es sich um eine Beschreibung aus einem Erste-Hilfe-Kurs handelt, in der _generell_ lauwarmes Wasser verwendet wird und mehr oder weniger einen hochdeutschen Satz abbildet. Im Gespräch mit einer befreundeten Slavistin merke ich, dass der Laut, den ich am Ende von "lauwoamen" Wasser mache wirklich sehr _verschwommen_ ist.

Answer (score -4):

beides falsch! Anhand einer längeren Formulierung kann man erkennen, dass dein *-n* genitiv ist.

> mittels des heiß-en Wassers

ob *mitten dem heißen* mal üblich war, weiß ich nicht. Persönlich finde ich, dass *-m* richtig klingt:

> *mitt('n) heißem Wasser*

sowie

> mit heißem Eisen gestrickt

> mit einem heißen Eisen

Comment: Dass *mittels* den Genitiv erfordert, hilft bei *mit* nicht weiter.

Comment: Der Genitiv hat die Frage "Wessen?", jedoch gehört das Wasser niemandem, außerdem kann ich, wenn ich jeden Satz beliebig umformuliere jeden anderen Fall erhalten. "Mit" erfordert im Standarddeutsch immer Dativ.

Comment: @Qohelet das ist putzig, dass du hier vom Wes-Fall reden möchtest.

Comment: @vectory - ich tue mir ob deiner improvisierten Antwort schwer, diesen Kommentar sinnvoll einordnen zu können

Comment: Ob *wegen des* des Genitivus erfordert, hilft *wegen dem* auch nicht weiter. Ja stimmt, war auch nicht Ziel meiner Antwort. Wenn du Hilfe in Schulgrammatik brauchst, war dir mit den ersteren Antworten bereits geholfen. Ich habe meinen Ansatz weiter verfolgt und so scheint mir der Casus Instrumental liege hier am nächsten, der im Germanischen zufällig ebenfalls mit -m gebildet wurde und alsbald vom Dativ ersetzt worden ist, der hier genauso unschlüssiv ist wie beim Kommitativ. Da insoweit zusätzlich für Neuter mit *-it* flektiert worden zu sein scheint, liegt nahe, dass *womit* ursprünglich war